# Dynamically adding textField in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is there a way to dynamically add textFields to the columnFooter in a Jasper Report.

I have situation where I might have to use:

```
  <columnFooter>
      <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="21"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Example text...."]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
```

or

```
      <columnFooter>
      <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="21"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Example text...."]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="21"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["More example text...."]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
```

(Or add any number of textFields.  Since I do not know how many will be added, I need to dynamically resize the band somehow) I'm looking for a way to dynamically do this in Java and not have to hardcode it in the jrxml file.  Thanks

Comment: You can use (JasperReports API)[http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/] or [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/api-docs/), for example

Comment: The first link seems to be dead, and can you point to what it is specifically about DynamicJasper API that enables me to do this? Perhaps a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Use second way with setting PrintWhenExpression on textFields and set "Remove Line When Blank" checkbox on properties of this textFields.

Comment: Sigh.. It really needs to be Dynamic.. In that particular example, I have two textFields, but it really could be any number... The point is, I don't know, and need a way to auto size the band when I put in x amounts of textFields

Answer (score 0):

If your report is created dynamically as JRDesign you can use the following:

```
JRDesignBand band = (JRDesignBand) jasperDesign.getColumnFooter();
        JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
        textField.setX(0);
        textField.setY(0);
        band.addElement(textField);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say but after years of working with JR Java API I have a feeling it was designed to print over fixed layout of document.
What could help in your case: if you know max number of fields that might appear, just add all them to the band, and set "remove line when blank" flag to true for each of them. It will collapse unused fields.